# Can't run powershell script from php

Tags: php, powershell, ssh, shell-exec, cisco

I use the Powershell script following to get a `show run` command run on a cisco device :

**getconfig.ps1**

```
$ErrorActionPreference ="Inquire"
Import-Module SSH-Sessions
$time ="$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)"
$filename ="config"
$ext =".txt"
$filepath ="temp\"
$d1 ="x.x.x.x"
$u1 ="user"
$p1 ="password"
New-SshSession $d1 -Username $u1 -Password "$p1"
$c1 ="show run"
$Results = Invoke-Sshcommand -InvokeOnAll -Command "$c1" | Out-File "$filepath$filename-$time$ext"
Remove-SshSession -RemoveAll
exit
```

When I run this script manually by right click/run with powershell that's worlking fine. The problem come when I try to run this script via PHP.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('powershell C:\wamp\www\getconf\script\getconfig.ps1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

index.php loads forever and never give me an output and never create the results file.

I have tried to run another script, like **test.ps1** that simply create a directory and it's working fine; I get the output and my directory is created.

My powershell script works.

The link between PHP and my PowerShell script works.

I do not understand where is the problem from.

Comment: try to hardcode the out-file path and ensure the webserver has access to it. If this works, use `split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` to get the path of the executing script.

Comment: Try to escape the $filepath ="temp\" propertly ($filepath ="temp\\")

Comment: Jisaak - You are my hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by jisaak the problem was that my webserver wasn't able to reach the destination directory.

By hardcoding the path properly the problem has been fixed.